# Mutually exclusive search options on MVC 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working up a view that will use 2 sets of search options and would like to know if there is better way than I'm headed.

on right hand side it will search by username, lastname
on left hand side it will search by an entity type or entity name
the results should be returned as a grid below the search.

I've considered that I may need 2 forms on the view but not sure if that is the right direction. Would 2 partial views each with their own form be better? If so, how would data be returned to the main view?

I'm trying to keep this simple by posting to controller actions and returning views instead of a bunch of confusing jquery.

Currently I have a model with 2 sub-models that each define the search fields that will allow a user to enter data into the textboxes.

What is the proper way to handle this in MVC 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two partial views if you are going to re-use the forms on other views or if you just want to encapsulate the view code.  I would suggest two forms that post to different controller actions 'SearchPerson(model), SearchEntity(model).  Both actions can return a common 'Results' view model to a 'SearchResults' view.

Comment: The partials wouldn't be used anywhere else but I still believe that is the right way to go just in case. Would you say that SearchResults would also be a partial and have it render on the same page as the 2 search partial? Because I can't navigate away from the search page just to return result, reqs state that returned results show on same page under search criteria entry. I've done this same thing before but used Telerik splitter. No 3rd party on this app tho so thinking the partials are the way to go as long as I can return results to same page

Comment: Yes, absolutely return SearchResults as a partial to the same page.  You'll be in a good position to enhance the page with ajax if the requirement comes up.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, I thought that felt right, just needed the sanity check!

Comment: I haven't fully implemented this yet but I'm feeling that I have a problem.
action-0 runs and renders View with partialview-1(usersearch), partialview-2(entitysearch), partialview-3(emptyresults).

partialview-1 submits to action-1 as a post sending model and retrieves list of results. If action-1 returns partialview-3 with results model, won't it render in the same spot that partialview-1 was in?